# Breaking a long PHP statement into multiple lines in my source code editor

Tags: php

```
if ( ! ( is_page( 'login' ) || bp_is_register_page() || is_page( 'lost-password' ) || is_page( 'reset-password' ) || ( is_page( 'home' ) && ! is_user_logged_in() ) ) ) {
```

What is the best way to break a PHP statement such as this into multiple lines in my source code editor? The main reason I want to do this is for easy reading and maintenance later down the line. I was thinking of something like:

```
if ( ! ( is_page( 'login' ) 
|| bp_is_register_page() 
|| is_page( 'lost-password' ) 
|| is_page( 'reset-password' ) 
|| ( is_page( 'home' ) 
&& ! is_user_logged_in() ) ) ) {
```

But that doesn't look quite right to me. It doesn't look 'tidy'. Is there a standard way of breaking a long PHP statement over multiple lines?

Comment: The only standard is readability. If something isn't readable, then it's bad. If something can be read fast and understood properly, then it's good

Comment: I don't thing there's a 'standard' way.  If it were me I'd indent everything after the first line.

Comment: "a" standard way? No. The nice thing about standards is there are so many to choose from.

Comment: I too would indent after the first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it.

```
if ( !( is_page( 'login' ) 
    || bp_is_register_page() 
    || is_page('lost-password') 
    || is_page('reset-password') 
    || (is_page('home') 
    && ! is_user_logged_in()))) 
{
    //code here
}
```

Normally I'd have the opening curly bracket on the same line as the if statement, but for such a long if statement putting it on its own line might be more readable.

Comment: This doesn't change anything in readability, there are still 3(!!!) curly brackets in a row. Just an identation added.

Comment: @mr.Pavlikov The indentation is a visual change.  It improves readability.  The OP wasn't asking what code to use.. He/she was asking how to present it.

Comment: That doesn't warrant a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!is_page('login') 
    && !bp_is_register_page() 
    && !is_page('lost-password') 
    && !is_page('reset-password') 
    && (!is_page('home') || is_user_logged_in())    
) {
```

Comment: Are you 100% certain your altered conditions do exactly the same as the original?

Comment: lolz.. you just changed his `||` or to `&&` and `!` is not

Comment: Yep !($a || $b) === !$a && !$b without too many of brackets, and ofc !($a && $b) = !$a || !$b

Comment: This looks way more pretty

Comment: This is how the Zend style guide recommends doing the indentation. No comment on the application of demorgan's laws :)

Comment: @Wooble, yep, this is Zendish:D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is_page is (assuming it's a function returning a string), but when you have multiple conditions based from the same variable, it's an excellent opportunity to use a switch function.

```
switch(is_page()){
  case 'lost-password':
    //do things
  break;
  case 'reset-password':
   //do things
  break;
  default:
    //if none of cases above, do things
  break;
}
```

Comment: Hi kcdwayne, thanks for your answer. It wasn't really the contents of the statement that mattered - my question was more to do with how to break long statements over multiple lines - i.e. how to format the statement i.e. best practice etc.